# Qt Raspberry Pi 3 Linux keyboard input

Tags: linux, qt, raspberry-pi, keyboard

I use a Raspberry Pi3 board, on Qt.5.15.11, in QT Creatore I wrote a test application based on QWidget - a button, EditBox, TextLabel, in short, HelloWorld. Compiled on a PC with Ubuntu using the cross-compile toolchain.

The Raspberry runs a Debian based Linux with an LXDE GUI. Qt is compiled with OpenGL support.

When I started my program, I found the following:

1. If you run the program as user (Pi), then the text from the keyboard can be entered in both Russian and English, switching the input language works fine. But if you run as administrator (sudo), then it prints only in English letters.
2. The appearance of the program also depends on whether it is launched as user (Pi) or us administrator (sudo).

Please tell me how to set up the input of Russian letters when starting the program as administrator?

And also, what does the appearance of the Qt program depend on (window sizes, frame appearance, font height ...) when launched as different users?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer on my question here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/872792/what-is-xdg-runtime-dir
In short - root and user (Pi) have different environment variables. Among the others, there ware those controlling behaviour of my application. To protect environment when running with sudo, I should use

```
sudo -E MyApp
```

By the way, I know that running the application as a root, I'm doing very, very bad. bcm2835.h contains instructions on how to get permissions when running as user. It uses libcap-dev. But I've not done it yet.